# Tcl/Tk front end to a database: how to show large amounts of relational data

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am developing a front end to a SQLite3 database in tcl/tk.  I extract some of the data I need to show using a query and calculate other columns in Tcl.  All the data is in a large list.  Now, I want to show this data in a structured format - it is tabular data and the number of columns is fixed, but the number of rows will depend on the criteria entered by the user (which determines the query's WHERE conditions and therefore determines the number of rows).

What I ideally want is a window in which there is a fixed frame on top with buttons to (a) close the window and (b) to show a summary table (which will be fixed format in terms of both rows and columns).  Then will come the table headers which I don't want to scroll out of view (so this will be another fixed frame, but the table may be wider than my window, so I need this part to be scrolled horizontally in sync with the actual data table that comes next).  Then comes the table which should have both horizontal and vertical scrollbars.  And then at the bottom is another fixed frame with buttons that take me to the first record and last record (without having to scroll up and down).

What is the best way to accomplish this in tk?  The frame at the top and the bottom, I can accomplish with not much effort.  The actual table is the part I am having trouble with.  I have thought about creating a frame for the data contents and gridding it with the data I need to display in the form of labels, but I don't know whether that will be fast.  I also don't know how to keep the headers from scrolling vertically out of view, but if I add separate scrollbars for it independent of the table, I don't know how to keep its horizontal scroll in sync with the horizontal scroll of the data below it.  I also don't know whether a frame can be scrolled vertically and horizontally.  As you can tell, I am somewhat new to this, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Show us a mockup drawing please (could be a powerpoint screenshot, or a photograph of scribbles on a napkin). Some code wouldn't hurt, but start with a drawing.

Comment: I'm guessing that the answer will be Tktable, and the queries will need work so that they can return subsets of the list of rows, a capability that SQLite definitely already has (and I'm pretty sure that Tktable doesn't need a fully instantiated data model to work and can instead call code to retrieve the parts it wants for display). Others will have more experience than I do at making all that work together, but that's where the solution lies…

Comment: I have uploaded a powerpoint slide with a mockup of what I am looking for here:  [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mGYsSIPYWErJwPh4nJ46RGKoFYL84paU).  Thank you

Comment: Thank you, Donal.  Yes, I already know how to query the db for the data I want.  I am new to tcl/tk, not to sqlite or sql databases in general, so getting the data out of the database is not the issue.  Displaying it is the primary issue.  Can a tktable scroll horizontally as well as vertically?  Can it have a fixed header that won't go out of view when scrolling the table vertically?  The tk documentation is so poor and mostly out of date that working with it is quite a chore.  Thank you.

Comment: The [docs are online](http://tktable.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tktable/tktable/doc/tkTable.html?revision=1.11) (for now). It supports the standard Tk scrolling protocol in both dimensions, and the `-usecommand`, `-command` and `-titlerows` options look relevant to your use case.

Comment: How many rows will be returned?  I found that for my purposes, trying to scroll more than a thousand rows was not possible (too many label widgets), and I wrote my own scrolling solution -- it's fast, but it doesn't have any horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Thank you all.  I figured out that the best solution for my use case is not TkTable, but TableList (http://www.nemethi.de/tablelist/tablelist.html).  Mainly because I don't see how to do the steps necessary to add TkTable to my installation of tcl/tk whereas TableList comes packaged with tcl/tk by default and has a lot more documentation.  I am going to give it a shot and see how it goes.